# Is "He's based in UK, but originally from Russia" a valid expression?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

"He's based in UK, but originally from Russia"

Is the quoted sentence a valid one? Can I use this to introduce someone who lives in UK but grew up in Russia?

Comment: I would say “in the UK”. (PS Ukraine doesn’t have a “the” anymore since it isn’t part of the Soviet Union).

Comment: But the UK isn't part of the Soviet Union either.

Comment: See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154680/when-do-we-use-definite-article-in-front-of-a-proper-noun-especially-for-an-uni

Answer (score 1):

Yes, almost everyone would understand that. It is a valid sentence.

Nevertheless, I'd not prefer to put 'originally;' more common is-

> *He's a Russian based in ***the*** UK*

[*based in*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/base_2) is used to say the place where you (mainly) work or live in. Calling him Russian makes his nationality clear.

Comment: But “from Russia” doesn’t mean he is Russian. Like a French guy who grew up in Moscow then moved to London.

Comment: @gnasher729 - Correct, but *originally from Russia* does.  Maulik has merely removed all reference to *originally from Russia* and summarized it to mean Russian.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common way of describing the situation in spoken English, at least here in the North America. If you need a more formal option, you can use something like "He is currently residing in the United Kingdom; however, his origin is Russian."

Comment: "Russian" here is an adjective.